# metatrader 5 don't let me make orders?

Tags: python-3.x, metatrader5

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bid'
```

from here

```
price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).bid
```

what's wrong?